# HTML post method vs AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to use AngularJS in my application, and at the initial stage I followed plain HTML for front view and for the back end potion I used a servlet and an ejb class where I organized SQL querys following CURD application method and that works really fine. Then I applied AngularJS that includes an Ajax call inside the `$scope` method. Once I create an Ajax method named "btnadd()", but now I cannot pass a value because the page directs to a servlet. Can any one help me to

```
<html ng-app="helloApp">
</head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="demoApp">
      <form name="frm" method="post" action="Srvlet">
        <input type="submit" name="btnadd" value="Add" ng-click="btnadd()"/>
```

My method in the JS file:

```
$scope.btnadd = function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: 'Srvlet',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
                datepicker: $scope.newcontact.datepicker,
                eId: $scope.newcontact.eId,
                name: $scope.newcontact.name, `enter code here`
                cmp: $scope.newcontact.cmp
              },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             console.log(data);
             $scope.$apply(function(){
                 $scope.newcontact.addRecordResult = data.addRecordResult;
             });
         },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.log('Error : ' + jqXHR.responseText);
         }
    });  if($scope.newcontact.eId == null) {
            $scope.newcontact.eId = departmentID++;
            $scope.Departments.push($scope.newcontact);
        } else {
            for(i in $scope.Departments) {
                if($scope.Departments[i].eId == $scope.newcontact.eId) {
                   $scope.Departments[i] = $scope.newcontact;
                }
            }
        }
    $scope.newcontact = {};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome on stackoverflow

I assume that the method `btnadd()` is attached to a submit button in which case it will proceed to the action. There is few possible solutions i.e. change submit button to standard button that wont send form but will call the method or/and add `onsubmit="return false;"` to form which will prevent form from sending

Although why don't you use an angularjs `$http`instead of jQuery? 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http